# Iterator end check fails after incrementing inside a `for` loop

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

This question is very likely to be a duplicate, but I have not found anything on this issue.

Why can incrementing an `iterator` placed at the last position in a `vector` make it not equal to `vector.end()`?

Or, in other words, why does this execute normally:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> vec = {"ve"};

    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {}

    return 0;
}
```

While this one goes into an infinite loop:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> vec = {"ve"};

    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) { it++; }

    return 0;
}
```

And this one:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> vec = {"ve"};

    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        cout << (it == vec.end()) << " ";
        cout << (*it == "ve") << endl;
        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

causes a `SEGFAULT` having printed:

```
0 1
0
```

so, `it`, in fact, was incremented, so that its contents became empty (optimised out, according to the debugger), but it did not become equal to `vec.end()`. Why?

Comment: Side-note: Don't use postfix increment in C++ for non-POD types when you don't use the result (easier: Always use prefix increment/decrement even for POD types just so you don't make a mistake with non-POD types). Postfix increment/decrement involves copy construction (and eventual destruction), where prefix increment/decrement can modify in place and return a reference cheaply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking for `it != vec.end()` but with `it++` happening twice you are skipping twice on each check. In other words you are running past the end of the `vector` without spotting it.

If you add one more element to your vector then the loop will hit the end and stop  as you will no longer skip the end point (obviously this is not a "proper" fix, it just demonstrates the problem).

To fix it check for end before the increment in the loop. You could also check using `operator<` in the conditional but that's a little risky as you're leaving an invalid `it` for a while which is bad for future maintenance of the code.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine `it` pointing to one before `vec.end()`, supposedly the last iteration of the `for` loop.

1. `it != vec.end();` will be `true`, so the loop will continue.
2. `it++;` in the body is executed. `it == vec.end()` now.
3. `it++` from the `for` loop head is executed. `it` points one **beyond** `vec.end()`.

`vec.end()` points **one** beyond the last element of `vec`, which is still well-defined. `vec.end() + 1` (the final value of `it`) points **two** beyond the last element of `vec`, which is undefined behavior.

That means that dereferencing the iterator accesses unallocated memory (**explaining the segmentation fault**). Undefined behavior again.

Answer (score 1):

In a for loop, the increment operation on the iterator is the last (and implicit) operation in a cycle.

Case 1: Loop begins with "it" = vec.begin(). Nothing happens. "it" is incremented (implicit). it = vc.end(). Loop ends. Hence the normal behavior.

Case 2: Loop begins with it = vec.begin(). "it" is incremented. it = vc.end(). "it" is incremented again (implicit). "it" moves to the next memory location, and keeps increasing in every cycle. Hence the infinite loop.

Case 3: Loop begins with it = vec.begin(). Check performed if it == vc.end(). Return false. Value in the memory location referenced by "it" is printed. "it" is incremented. it = vc.end(). "it" is incremented again (implicit). "it" moves to the next memory location, which is unallocated. Hence the SEG fault.